Windows 11 does not boot even in safe mode after cloning
I have a new clear notebook, maked an ssd image on old notebook and restored on new.
On new notebook Windows 11 freezes on booting on startup screen in normal or safe mode.
I trying to enable bootlog, but windows\ntbtlog.txt is not created after boot try (I enabled boot loging in msconfig on source system and after that clone system).
Image of source system is valid, I restored it and check boot on virtual PC.
Help me please, how I can check what driver cause a system freeze?
Thanks


If an old notebook was images, then that image was applied to a new notebook (e.g. an entirely different machine), that can't be done in this manner, as Windows isn't designed like that. The only way to do so is on the old notebook, SysPrep /Generalize must be run (it will delete all users and user data) and once done, it must be booted to WinPE/WinRE and a WIM captured. Once captured, the WIM can be applied to the new notebook's SSD and Windows booted

(Cont'd...) It's usually more efficient to clean install Windows and reinstall all software. When clean installing, the CPU chipset drivers must be installed immediately upon exiting OOBE when you're at the Desktop, as they must be installed prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates (not doing so will result in random, wonky issues over time that a repair install will not fix). Once done, reboot, then configure Windows Update to install drivers via it's Settings page, run Windows Update, and reboot when it says, repeating until no updates are left, then install software.

Thanks, I install new windows. Problem only with notebook - other images restored and working fine (windows 10 from other notebook and pc)

It's never recommended to move Windows from one machine to another, it's not supported and is why SysPrep exists. The reason is machine IDs and OEM drivers that get installed to %WinDir%\INF, many times as oem###.inf - because these are OEM hardware drivers, they're never meant to be uninstalled, so no uninstaller exists for them. When SysPrep /Generalize is run, it removes all machine-specific info from the OS partition, including OEM drivers, so a WIM can be captured & applied to another machine (it's how OEMs and businesses mass deploy Windows to machines through ZTI deployments)

On my working PC windows came from 7 to 10 version, and I changed a lot of hardware configs. Its a first case where windws does not working after cloning

Quoting directly from the linked to man page: "Before you can deploy a Windows image to new PCs, you have to first generalize the image. Generalizing the image removes computer-specific information such as installed drivers and the computer security identifier (SID). You can either use Sysprep by itself or Sysprep with an unattend answer file to generalize your image and make it ready for deployment." SysPrep isn't optional, it's a requirement for this

I understand things can work, but if you were to delve into Event Viewer overtime, it's likely errors populate over time, especially due to different chipset drivers installed that don't match the motherboard and CPU (there is no way to uninstall chipset drivers, once they're installed, they're installed until removed by SysPrep /Generalize). What's being asked is about an unsupported Windows configuration being deployed in a way unsupported by Windows - e.g. Windows is operating as designed, this is not supported - best advice is to clean install, which you've done
